# MySQL DISTINCT and accents

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

A MySQL database running on Debian (version 5.5.41-0+wheezy1-log).

A table `hotels` with a column `name VARCHAR(128)` and engine is InnoDB.

```
CREATE TABLE `hotels` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Hotel Name',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

There are two records in this table:

```
1    BEST WESTERN PREMIER LE CARRE FOLIES OPERA
2    BEST WESTERN PREMIER LE CARRÉ FOLIES OPÉRA
```

When executing `select DISTINCT name FROM hotels`, the query is returning only 1 record, while 2 records were expected to be returned.

The DBMS doesn't seem to distinct between E and É.

How to change the table settings in order to get the expected result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The table collation was set to `utf8_general_ci`. This was the default setting of the MySQL server and the schema.

There are 3 collation names available in MySQL 5.5:

- A name ending in `_ci` indicates a case-insensitive collation.
- A name ending in `_cs` indicates a case-sensitive collation.
- A name ending in `_bin` indicates a binary collation. Character comparisons are based on character binary code values.

The collation had to be changed to `utf8_bin`. This can be done for the table and all columns with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE hotels CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```